# installing the ADT plugin behind an authenticated HTTP proxy

Tags: android, eclipse, adt, proxy-authentication

I am trying to get the Android ADT pluging on a 64 bit eclipse indigo installation on a windows 7 home premium machine. My system is situated behind an authenticated http proxy.

I tried setting the http & https (not SOCKS because that caused other errors) which basically downloads the list of packags under ADT but is unable to download the packages (gets stuck around 35% every time).

Making changes in eclipse.ini as suggested on some forums causes eclipse to not even download the list of packages.

The problem is eclipse doesnt want to download somee of the files though it manages to get a few of them (though never enough to install a complete package)

I have proxy settings set in 1)primary browser- Firefox 2)Internet Options in Control panel 3)eclipse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can download the ADT plugins as an archive and install that locally. For detailed instructions, see http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html#Troubleshooting

Comment: Is that the only way? the site also mentions I would need to do this process manually every time the SDK manager updates resulting in the requirement of updating the ADT plugin.

Comment: You can always try updating the regular way through your proxy, but if that doesn't work this is your only option. Well, you could try to get someone to mirror the Eclipse update sites inside your proxy, but that's not a small undertaking.

Answer (score 0):

open the link mentioned by E-Riz and
download the zip file and open eclipse and add new software - add- archive(locate to the place where u downloaded) this would help u install the plugin